# <a click=''> event binding in SPA using router.navigate

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal, single-page-application, amd

I have small requirement that i want to navigate to productdetail module from products grid.

Products Grid contains the below

Product Id   |  Product Name

[123977844](http://www.google.com) | HTC OneX

```
var router = require('plugins/router');
    router.navigate('welcome')
```

i want to navigate to other module(productdetails) when i click Product Id link using SPA, durandal, require js and knockout js.
Can any one help on...

Regards,
Shiva

Comment: What you tried so far? What is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

**Add the route in the HTML as a normal link:**

```
<a data-bind="attr:{href: '/#product/' + ProductId}, text: ProductName"></a>
```

(Replace `ProductId` and `ProcuctName` with your properties)

**Add a click handler:**

Assuming the HTML is inside a foreach while iterating through a products array.

```
 <a href="#" data-bind="text: ProductName, click: $parent.goToProduct"></a>
```

ViewModel:

```
var router = require('plugins/router');

var vm = {
    goToProduct: function(product){
        router.navigate('product/' + product.ProductId);
    }
```

Comment: Link approuch is better since users can use that to share product link with others etc

Comment: I agree, however using the `router.navigate` doesn't mean that the unique URL is not going to be displayed in the navigation bar, users can still navigate to the view and share the URL.

Comment: True, but a link should be a link :D

Comment: A link can also be opened in a new tab by pressing middle mouse button

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I'm just pointing options available ;)

Comment: how do i get ProductId in product details pages

Comment: ProductId should be a property of the object that is bound to the context of your view. Are you iterating through an array to display the items in the grid? Which objects does  the array contain?

Comment: my question was not clear to you.I mean when i click orderid , then it will redirect to orderdetails view, how do i get product id in other page. is there any changes in shell.js for passgin as query string?

Comment: You can get the new details by calling the server with the Id that you got in the activation method or use another system like application messaging in Durandal. Post another question about this since it's hard to explain this in a comment..